# A good alternative to this use of CSS "width: fit-content" in a responsive layout?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, responsive

I'm working on creating a responsive layout for this website: https://json-z.org/

The layout follows a typical pattern of spreading out horizontally when screen real estate permits, but then using more and more vertical stacking of components as screen/window dimensions narrow.

At phone-sized portrait widths, however, I found I needed to squeeze things just a bit more than vertically stacking could accomplish. My first method of paring down required width looked like this:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 374px) {
  .details-wrapper {
    margin: -10% -15% -15% -10%;
  }

  .details {
    transform: scale(0.80);
  }
}
```

This got the job done, but I really wanted something that smoothly applied just as much scaling down as necessary, and no more, for any particular screen width, and that also automatically computed just the right margins to match any particular scaling factor.

To make a long story short, I created an Angular component to do the job, and the code can be found here: [shrink-wrap.component.ts](https://github.com/kshetline/json-z-demo/blob/master/src/app/widgets/shrink-wrap/shrink-wrap.component.ts), [shrink-wrap.component.html](https://github.com/kshetline/json-z-demo/blob/master/src/app/widgets/shrink-wrap/shrink-wrap.component.html), [shrink-wrap.component.scss](https://github.com/kshetline/json-z-demo/blob/master/src/app/widgets/shrink-wrap/shrink-wrap.component.scss).

What concerns me is that I'm relying on `width: fit-content` to make this work.

```css
.outer-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.sizer {
  height: 1px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1000;
}

.inner-wrapper {
  overflow: visible;
  position: relative;
  width: -moz-fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
}
```

The [MDN website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width) describes `fit-content` as:

> This is an experimental API that should not be used in production code.

Despite this warning, however, the CSS is working well for Chrome on Windows and Mac, Firefox on Windows and Mac, and Safari on Mac and iOS (as tested on both a big iPhone XS Plus and a tiny iPhone 5S). It works OK on Edge for typical desktop usage, but falls a part a bit at very narrow window sizes.

Oddly enough, the following is *not* listed as experimental:

```
.some-class {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: fit-content(100%);
  ...
```

...but wasn't anywhere near as compatible across as many browsers.

Can anyone recommend a better alternative to `fit-content`?

What I need is for the container of the panel I'm trying to shrink to go no smaller than the minimum the panel requires, while both a sibling of that container, and the parent of both, get smaller as screen/window width demand.

[image: element screen shot]

While `inner-wrapper` is 362 pixels wide, `sizer` and `outer-wrapper` are both only 336 pixels wide, and it's precisely this ratio, 336/362, that tells me the exact amount of scaling that I need.

Comment: Please use ```vw``` for varying width like ```100vw``` or ```vh``` for ```xxvh```.

Comment: The sizing doesn't necessarily have to be relative to screen or window width, but could instead be sizing relative to a different containing element, so vw/vh units aren't necessarily appropriate.

Comment: ```vh/vw``` responses to the closest most outer element. Or take ```width: 100%; margin: 5vw``` (as required).

Comment: I don't necessarily want to reference "the closest most outer element". This needs to be flexible enough to scale to inner elements as well.

Comment: It gets auto-scaled.

Comment: I suspect were not talking about the same things at this point! :)